# Any hints on the xsd bloat created by a WCF web service reference in a Silverlight 3 project?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, xsd, wsdl

I've a Silverlight 3 based project, talking with a DB via a WCF web service. So far, so good.

I'm growing more and more concerned about the sheer number of xsd and wsdl files generated in the servicereference subfolder.

The increasing numbers seems to be a kind of versioning, but I'm not sure...

Do you know what is it for? It seems not to be included in the resulting .xap... 
where may I find an article on this stuff?

Comment: Rather than talking about "bloat", why not look at the files and understand what's in them? You'd then be able to intelligently discuss the nature of the "bloat" and offer suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: +1 Seems like a reasonable question to me.  @John "why not look at the files and understand what's in them?" huh?? You might as well say "stop asking questions and go understand things for yourself".

Comment: @Anthony: that's not at all the same. The files he's talking about are XML Schema and WSDL files. These are published, international standards. How can he possibly understand enough to call them "bloat" if he doesn't understand what they are for? Maybe the files are actually as good as possible - but without understanding WSDL and XSD, there is no way to determine this.

Comment: @Anthony: a reasonable question would be, "why is this particular XSD file created when I don't use any elements from its target namespace", but you'd have to be able to read XSD to ask that question. In the absence of understanding, the best the OP can do is assume that it's "bloat" because of the number of files.

Comment: @John: Sounds to me you're just getting bee in your bonnet over the misuse of the word "bloat".  A misuse that seems to derive from a lack of knowledge.  A lack of knowledge that lead Vinzz to ask a question.  We cannot be jumping on people for displaying a lack of knowledge by the way they use words.  Its the search for knowledge that brings people here in the first place.

Comment: @Anthony: and we cannot shy away from giving our knowledge out of fear that people will be offended. In this case, knowledge of the correct use of the term "bloat".

Comment: @Anthony: BTW, Google Translate (http://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT#en|fr|bloat) suggests there may be less understanding than you may think. So does the question, "I'm growing more and more concerned about the sheer number of xsd and wsdl files generated in the servicereference subfolder." He's concerned about the number of files - files whose contents he does not understand. I see nothing wrong with suggesting he come to an understanding of what's in the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really bloat. When WCF generates WSDL it references external documents. Supposedly, this is the proper way to do it, but enough programming stacks choke on it that multiple people have come up with ways of [flattening the WSDL](http://steverb.com/post/Flatten-WCF-WSDL-on-Demand.aspx).

You can read all about the Service Description at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738723.aspx